# Data Migration - Replication vs Bulk API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, bulk-api, data-migration, replication

I'm curious to understand the pros and cons of the [Replication API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_datareplication.htm) and the [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm)

When migrating 20 objects with approximately 75MM rows, which would you choose? Why? Which would be fastest? Why?

Answer (score 2):

The two APIs have different, albeit sometimes complementary, purposes.

The Replication API is designed to assist in ongoing synchronization of an external data store with Salesforce. It is not suitable for performing an initial multi-million record data migration.

The Bulk API is a suitable choice for one-off extraction and migration at that data volume. Should you then wish to perform ongoing synchronization, you'd want to use Replication.

Comment: Any thoughts on the speed portion of this? Is the replication api slower for the initial pull down than the bulk api?

Comment: @techbusinessman These APIs have completely different purposes. You can't compare them for doing a 75 million row extraction because you cannot use the Replication API to do that at all. See the [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getupdated.htm#topic-title) in the documentation - it tops out at 30 days/600,000 records.

Comment: My understanding is it's 600k Ids per call. Ultimately, the replication api is already being used to do the pull and currently works in our use case. Trying to figure out if bulk will be quicker though.

Comment: Interesting. How are you accounting for the 30 day maximum window on getUpdated()?

Comment: I have never benchmarked these two APIs against one another but I would be prepared to wager heavily on the Bulk API.